# Running J2ME (Java Micro Edition) Applications

Tags: java

What's the easiest way to run J2ME (Java phone apps) on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MicroEmulator it is a pure Java implementation of Java ME in Java SE. You can find its [homepage on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/microemulator/).

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure if you download Java development environment from Sun, it will allow you to run J2ME.

Comment: The development environment?  Doesn't that contain things like javac?  Don't I mostly need libraries to go with my java interpreter?